# How do I check if a generic parameter is of a specific type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I can do this

```
private static void Execute<T>(IList<T> points, ...) where T : Point2D
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Point3D)) // Point3D only
    {
```

but I would like to check against `Point3D` and all derived types, something like:

```
private static void Execute<T>(IList<T> points, ...) where T : Point2D
{
    if (T is Point3D) // Point3D ans derived types
    {
```

but I get: *Error CS0119: 'T' is a type, which is not valid in the given context*

`Point3D` class inherits from `Point2D` one.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: `private static void Execute<T>(IList<T> points, ...) where T : Point3D` didn't work for you?

Comment: Are you sure whatever you are doing is a good idea? `Point3D` / `Point2D` should in most cases be struct, to improve memory usage and locality, since there is likely a lot of points. Using derived types goes counter to this goal, and arguably, a point3D *is not* a point2D, but may have properties like `XY` to *convert* to a Point2D. Using *interfaces* as generic restrictions might be appropriate, but then you should use the interface, and avoid explicit type checks.

Comment: `typeof(Point3D).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of the `Type.IsAssignableTo`/`Type.IsAssignableFrom` :

> `IsAssignableTo` - Determines whether the current type can be assigned to a variable of the specified targetType.

> `IsAssignableFrom` - Determines whether an instance of a specified type c can be assigned to a variable of the current type.

```cs
if(typeof(T).IsAssignableTo(typeof(Point3D)))
```

Note that `IsAssignableTo` was introduced in .NET 5, so for earlier framework version you need to use the "reverse":

```
if(typeof(Point3D).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
```

Comment: If I have `Point4D` that inherits from `Point3D` will it return true?

Comment: @abenci yes, since `Point3D x = new Point4D()` is a valid statement.

Comment: I get this error, is this method specific of some C# language version?  *Error CS1061: 'Type' does not contain a definition for 'IsAssignableTo' and no accessible extension method 'IsAssignableTo' accepting a first argument of type 'Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Comment: @abenci This method was added in .NET 5.

Comment: @abenci use the "reverse" `if(typeof(Point3D).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))`